# Plotly.Net.CSharp: how to change trace color using trace.SetValue() method

Tags: c#, plotly

I am new to C# Syntax. Right now I am trying to highlight scatter points in a Plotly diagram using their individual colors. The code looks something like this:

```
//some variable definitions including total_points which is supposed to be the total number of points generated for the scatter plot

int[] x_list = new int[total_points];
int[] y_list = new int[total_points];
Color[] color_list = new Color[total_points];

for (int i = 0; i<total_points; i++)
{
//Write Values for x,y and the color to their respective lists for every datapoint
}

int[] x = x_list;
int[] y = y_list;

LinearAxis xAxis = new LinearAxis();
xAxis.SetValue("title", "x values");
xAxis.SetValue("showgrid", true);
xAxis.SetValue("showline", true);

LinearAxis yAxis = new LinearAxis();
yAxis.SetValue("title", "y values");
yAxis.SetValue("showgrid", true);
yAxis.SetValue("showline", true);

Layout layout = new Layout();
layout.SetValue("xaxis", xAxis);
layout.SetValue("yaxis", yAxis);
layout.SetValue("showlegend", true);
layout.SetValue("plot_bgcolor", "#e5ecf6");

Trace trace = new Trace("scatter");
trace.SetValue("x", x);
trace.SetValue("y", y);
trace.SetValue("mode", "markers");
trace.SetValue("name", "datapoints");


GenericChart
    .ofTraceObject(true, trace)
    .WithLayout(layout)
    .Show();
```

I have looked up this issue online and the only thing I can find is something like:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13],
    name='trace02',
    mode='lines+markers',
    marker=dict(size=[0, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0],
            color=[0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0])
))
```

however I do not know how to "translate" this to a Method like `trace.SetValue()`